# Is there a way to know if Identifier node is a variable name when traversing AST?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-plugin

I am writing a babel plugin and I would like to collect all the variables used in a particular expression. For this I am using `path.traverse()` with `Identifier` visitor. However, this approach is not ideal as things like property names are also classified as identifiers, while I am interested only in actual variables (identifiers that declare/access bindings in scope + global variables). So, currently, I'm doing something like this:

```js
expressionPath.traverse({
  Identifier(path) {
    const {node, parent} = path;
    if (!isVariableName({node, parent})) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('identifier is a variable name', node.name);
  }
});

function isVariableName({node, parent}) {
  if (types.isProperty(parent) || types.isMethod(parent)) {
    const isPropertyName = !parent.computed && node === parent.key;
    return !isPropertyName;
  }
  if (
    types.isMemberExpression(parent) ||
    types.isOptionalMemberExpression(parent)
  ) {
    const isPropertyName = !parent.computed && node === parent.property;
    return !isPropertyName;
  }
  if (types.isPrivateName(parent)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

I find this not ideal either, as I need to consider all possible use cases for identifiers (I can miss some or there can be more with new JS features - e.g. private class property names are also identifiers). `scope.getBinding()` also doesn't help much here, as global variables do not have bindings (just like property names do not) and there can actually be a binding for a certain identifier name in scope, but the identifier itself can be a property name.

Do you know a better solution? I would also like to know if a variable is being declared or accessed/mutated but this is a different question I think.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out babel already provides methods to check if a certain `Identifier` is a variable:

1. `path.isBindingIdentifier()` returns `true` if the identifier creates a binding in the scope (e.g. a variable is being declared).
2. `path.isReferencedIdentifier()` - if a variable (including globals) is being referenced. This one is mentioned in babel handbook: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#toc-check-if-an-identifier-is-referenced

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for spotting a typo! I also found some brief reference in the docs and attached them.